# kentico product options not adjusting prices when choosing different options

Tags: kentico

I am using the RandomProducts web part, and for some reason product options have no effect on the price even though I have added the price adjustments for each variant. Is this normal? I assumed this would work out of the box since its a default option but maybe I have to write my own code... just seems odd. Does something need to be enabled for product options to update the price of a product?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not having an JS issues on your page? When using the Product Options, you define the option and any adjustment to the price. You then choose the products to apply the option to. When a user selects a specific option, there is a postback that occurs that updates the displayed price. If using the CartItemSelector web part, it will contain all of the postback JS needed to update the price within itself.

This works on a basic demo site so I suspect there is a JS issue that is causing the postback to not complete properly.

Another possible cause could be latency when posting the value back. If it is the first time you are running the site, it's possible the postback is taking longer than expected (due to recompilation) and it is appearing as if it's failing.

Other things to check:

On the Product Options General Tab
- Is "Enabled" checked?
- Is "Display price adjustments" checked?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to check the following things:

- JavaScript errors via the developer tools of your browser
- Caching settings/expiration for the web part or page
- Enable SQL debug (Settings > System > Debug > Display on live site) and check which queries are executed to see where the price comes from